# How can I determine the exact number of digits entered after the decimal point?

Tags: c

For example, when I input a `float` or a `double` and the user enters

```
2.33
```

then, when I print this number, I get:

```
2.330000
```

However, the user did not enter these trailing zeroes after the decimal point.

How can I determine the number of digits the user entered after the decimal point and output the number the user entered exactly, without the trailing zeroes?

Comment: If you convert the input to a float, there's no way to know how many digits the user typed after the decimal point.

Comment: BTW, `.` is decimal point, not comma.

Comment: When you read a number as a decimal integer, there's no way of knowing whether it was typed as, say, `123` or `0123` or `000123`.  Similarly, when you read a number as a floating-point number, those trailing 0's are not significant and are not recorded in any way, either.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know exactly what the user entered, instead of to what value that input was converted, then you must read the input as a string, instead of as a `float` or `double`. You can use the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) for that. This also allows you to count the number of digits after the decimal point that were entered:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    char buffer[100], *p;
    double converted;

    //number of digits after the decimal point
    int num_digits = 0;

    printf( "Please enter a floating-point number: " );

    if (
        fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL
        ||
        ( p = strchr(buffer,'\n') ) == NULL
    )
    {
        //fgets failed or line was too long, so quit program
        printf( "input error!\n" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //remove newline character from input
    *p = '\0';

    //skip digits until `.` found
    for ( p = buffer; *p != '.'; p++ )
    {
        if ( *p == '\0' )
        {
            printf( "unable to find '.' character in line!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if ( !isdigit( (unsigned char)*p ) )
        {
            printf( "ERROR: Found non-digit before '.' character!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    //skip over '.' character
    p++;

    //The '.' character has now been found and skipped.
    //Now, count number of digits after that character.
    for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
    {
        if ( !isdigit( (unsigned char)*p ) )
        {
            printf( "ERROR: Found non-digit after '.' character!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        num_digits++;
    }

    //convert input to double-precision floating-point
    converted = strtod( buffer, NULL );

    printf( "You entered %d digits after the decimal point.\n", num_digits );
    printf( "Your input as a string is: %s\n", buffer );
    printf( "Your input as a double is: %f\n", converted );
    printf(
        "When printing this double with %d digits of precision: %.*f\n",
        num_digits, num_digits, converted
    );

}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter a floating-point number: 2.33
You entered 2 digits after the decimal point.
Your input as a string is: 2.33
Your input as a double is: 2.330000
When printing this double with 2 digits of precision, you get: 2.33
```

Note that this program is not a perfect solution. It is a bit limited in that it only allows you to enter digits and a decimal point. It does not allow you to enter negative numbers (which would require a `'-'` character) and also does not allow you to enter floating-point numbers using exponential notation. This would require additional work to implement. This program is only intended as a simple example of how you could do it.

After reading the user input as a string and counting the number of entered digits after the decimal point, you still have the option of converting it to a `float` or `double`, for example using the function [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof), as demonstrated in the example program above. Or you can simply print the string that the user entered, as is also demonstrated in the example program.

Another option you have is when using `printf`, you can specify the number of digits printed after the decimal point, by specifying the "precision" of the output. See the documentation for the function [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for further information. This is also demonstrated in my example program.